# How is the memory allocated for an array defined (declared?) in a header file?

Tags: c

Say, there is a proc.h which defines an array like

proc.h:

```
struct proc
{
 char p_stat;
 char p_flags;
 int p_pid;
} proc[100];
```

And there are another 5 .c files including this header file. I did not see any of such .c files allocate the memory for this array. I think it's linker that allocates the memory for it.  However, what appears in the header file should be just a declaration. How could a declaration causes the memory allocation? I thought only definition will cause the memory allocation.

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't accepted an answer for this old question :) Any reasons why?

Answer (score 3):

> Say, there is a proc.h which defines an array like
>
> proc.h:
>
> ```
> struct proc 
> {  
>     char p_stat;  
>     char p_flags;  
>     int p_pid; 
> } proc[100];
> ```

The code above actually not only defines the data structure `struct proc`, it also declares/allocates an array of them for each file including the header.

A widely used idiom is to define the data structure with a typedef, like so:

```
 typedef struct 
 {  
     char p_stat;  
     char p_flags;  
     int p_pid; 
 } proc_t;
```

or just plain old defining the structure without the typedef:

```
 struct 
 {  
     char p_stat;  
     char p_flags;  
     int p_pid; 
 } proc_t;
```

and then in the c-file matching the header, you'll instantiate your array of structs:

```
proc_t proc[100];        // if you've typedef'd the struct
struct proc_t proc[100]; // if you haven't typedef'd
```

and then in all the c-files including the header, wanting access to this global struct, you'll declare the variable extern. That way, all the c-files will share access to a single data structure.

I prefer to typedef a structure in a single header and encapsulate it by only accessing/manipulating instantiations of that data structures through function calls (objects passed by address), but that is a matter of personal taste and whatevs.

Comment: I agree - I think my answer more directly answers what OP asked, but this answer is really what he needs to know. :) +1

Answer (score 2):

The `include` directive does nothing more than insert the included file into the file which includes it. In other words, all `.c` files declare the structure separately, and declare (allocate memory) for the variable `proc`. They all define memory for it *separately*. If all of them are later compiled together, I have no idea how can this possible work properly.

Comment: I'm referring the Lions' commentary of Unix 6th edition. Believe it or not, that is what I saw... http://warsus.github.io/lions-/. Line #0376 is the definition of the array in proc.h. And you will find quite a few "#include ../proc.h"

Answer (score 2):

> I did not see any of such .c files allocate the memory for this array.

Actually, they all do: the declaration and the definition are copied verbatim into each translation unit that includes the header, so each translation unit gets its own definition of the `proc[100]` array.

If you try linking the results of translation together, you should see a redefinition error produced by the linker, unless the actual header declares `proc` static.

Of course the proper way of creating `proc[100]` would be to declare it `extern` in the header, and provide a definition in one of the `.c` files.

Answer (score 2):

'header' files are *included* (become part of) a C file. You have declared and defined the array in your header file and then included that declaration into your five C files, so the space gets allocated 5 times. What you want to do is make the `proc` array an `extern` declaration in the header file, and then copy the exact same declaration (without the `extern`) in one of your C files.

Or, you can accomplish much the same thing with macros, like so:

```
// foo.h
#ifndef MAIN
  /*
   * this declaration is extern for everybody except the 
   * MAIN module, (typically main.c) which defines
   * the macro MAIN -- this ensures that all C files see the same 
   * structure definition, but space is allocated exactly once.
   */
   extern struct proc {
#else
          struct proc {
#endif
     … 
    } proc[100];
```

in one of your C files, (e.g. main), you do this:

```
// main.c
#define MAIN
// when you include foo.h, the 'extern' will be left out, and space will be allocated
#include "foo.h"
```

in your other C files, you just do this:

```
// other.c
#include "foo.h"
```

This will cause space for the array to be allocated once (in main.o) and the other .o files will contain external references to proc[] which will be resolved by the linker.

Comment: the `MAIN` macro method seems like a great way to create a WTF-like unreadable code. Declare the structure in a header, declare a variable in specific `.c`, declare `extern` in a separate header or also `.c`.

Comment: You think it's preferable to have an extern declaration and a final declaration that are not guaranteed to be the same? The MAIN macro makes sure everybody always uses the same structure definition. I consider this a good thing. If you find it confusing, it would only take a line or two of comments to clear that up for the reader.

Comment: @Dariusz - see revised code, commented to reduce WTF-ness while maintaining the safety of a single declaration.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Even after the edit. Invalid extern will be reported. Your way I have to remember a weird macro with either massively complex name or absolutely meaningless name. And first and foremost, I would never put a variable declaration in a header. 
Still, it's just an opinion. I acknowledge the validity of this solution.

Comment: I agree re: putting the definition in a header in the first place. I didn't address it, because it wasn't what the OP asked, but I think @Morten Jensen's answer is really the 'right' thing to do: declare a typedef and an external ref to the array in the header, and declare the actual array in one file.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I think. In case of those two ... codes ... yours is definitely better than the OP's.

Answer (score 1):

As Morten Jensen noted, it is the same as doing:

```
typdef struct proc
{
   // ...
} proc_t;

proc_t proc[100];
```

which is a *definition* of proc (not just a declaration). However this is probably a mistake. If this header is included in more than one translation unit, then *it is undefined behaviour*.

(I am posting this answer because all of the other answers so far say that it creates multiple copies of `proc`, however that is wrong!)

It's undefined behaviour to have two (or more) definitions of an externally-visible variable.

---

If the intent is to have a single variable visible from multiple units, then `proc_t proc[100];` needs to be replaced with the declaration:

```
extern proc_t proc[100];
```

and then exactly one unit does the definition `proc_t proc[100]`.

If the intent is for all units to have separate copies of `proc`, then replace with this definition:

```
static proc_t proc[100];
```

In both cases, `proc` has what is called *static storage duration*. This means that the memory is allocated during program startup.